# How to ignore a NameError and continue running the rest of the program?

Tags: python, web-scraping, error-handling

The code I'm using has been working occasionally, but I need something to work all the time. The site I'm scraping sometimes has the info and other times omits it, which is why I get the error after running the program. Since the site doesn't always post a time for certain events, 'event_time' obviously is not defined.

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes the `with suppress(Exception):` works and sometimes it doesn't. What can I add to skip over the the event_time when the site doesn't specify a time, and have the program continue to scrape the rest of the site?

```
event_name = s.select_one('.eventname').get_text(strip=True)
event_day = s.select_one('.date').text.strip()
event_month = s.select_one('.month').text.strip()
with suppress(Exception):
    event_time = s.select_one('.time').text.strip()
event_info = s.select_one('.event-header').text.strip()
```

Error:

```
NameError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-45cf21eb3177> in <module>
     22     print('Dia: ' + event_day)
     23     print('Mes: ' + event_month)
---> 24     print('Hora: ' + event_time)
     25     print('Descripción: ' + event_info)
     26     print('-' * 80)

NameError: name 'event_time' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of supressing the exception

```
with suppress(Exception): 
    event_time = s.select_one('.time').text.strip()
```

catch it and add a default

```
try:
    event_time = s.select_con('.time').text.strip()
except Exception:
    event_time = ''
```

Catching a generic exception can hide other errors. Its best to figure out which exceptions can happen and catch those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-except statement to ensure that the exception is caught every time.

```
try:
    event_time = s.select_con('.time').text.strip()
except NameError:
    event_time = ...
```